# How to render form field with information that it is required

Tags: django, forms, field

Is there any clever way to make django forms render field with asterisks after fields that are required? Or to provide some other clever for to mark required fields? I wouldn't like to have to do it again in a template if I already set a field as required in the form.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As of Django 1.2, if your form has an attribute named `required_css_class`, it will be added to `BoundField.css_classes` for required fields. You can then use CSS to style the required parts of the form as desired. A typical use case:

```
# views.py
class MyForm(django.forms.Form):
    required_css_class = 'required'
    …
```

…

```
/* CSS */
th.required { font-weight: bold; }
```

…

```
<!-- HTML -->
<tr>
  <th class="{{form.name.css_classes}}">{{form.name.label_tag}}</th>
  <td>{{form.name.errors}}{{form.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

If you use `Form.as_table()`, `Form.as_ul`, and `Form.as_p`, they do this automatically, adding the class to `<tr>`, `<li>`, and `<p>`, respectively.

Comment: Note you can use css content directive to add an asterisk using same this method: `th.required:after { content: '*' }`

Answer (score 13):

You also can use a field.field.required property:

```
{% for field in form %}
  {{field.label}} {% if field.field.required %} * {% endif %}
  {{field}}
  {{field.errors}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Perfect. This solution will be required in case you are looping over the form fields and rendering every field separately using `{% for field in form %}` etc., instead of rendering the whole form using `{{ form }}`

Answer (score 1):

The best way for such purposes I have found is to render form's output via an html template. How to do this is described [here](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/TemplatedForm). By luck, the example puts an asterisk after required fields just like you want.

Comment: None of my forms is rendered {{ form }}, I explicitly call fields, because I usually display only subset of form's fields. I need something lower, like an attribute of a field or a widget.

Comment: If you are talking about modelforms and using 'fields' property of the Meta class to determine a subset of fields to display, this will work. If you have non-model forms and have hidden fields, again it will work. I am in a haste, sorry if I am missing something?

Comment: I have a single Form that is used in many templates and I usually call all the fields I need in the template. That's why I can't use templated rendering.

But it seems it would be better, If I just created some subclasses with Meta and then use this templating. That's good idea, I have to think about it.

Comment: I'm looping through all fields of a form, so this did wonders for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I use a template tag to render form fields with their labels and errors, plus an asterisk and a CSS class for required fields. There are various snippets available to do it on www.djangosnippets.org

Comment: So do I at the moment, I mean I use a filter to do this. Still, this isn't very dry. I'd prefer to put this setting into the form (some 'mark_required=True' in form).

Answer (score 0):

Personny I tried something like this, i.e. overriding the default template tag (this adds a red asterisk in all the admin interface for required not-readonly fields. Then i also defined a 2nd tag for my views that mix inline and block labels. See the code below (copy/paste of Django source code with some modifications):

In settings.py :

```
from django.forms.util import flatatt
from django.utils.html import conditional_escape
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
import django.forms.forms as django_forms
def custom_label_tag(self, contents=None, attrs=None):
        """
        Wraps the given contents in a <label>, if the field has an ID attribute.
        Does not HTML-escape the contents. If contents aren't given, uses the
        field's HTML-escaped label.

        If attrs are given, they're used as HTML attributes on the <label> tag.
        """
        contents = contents or conditional_escape(self.label)
        widget = self.field.widget
        id_ = widget.attrs.get('id') or self.auto_id
        if id_:
            attrs = attrs and flatatt(attrs) or ''
            if self.field.required:
                label = unicode(contents)
                label_suffix = ""
                if label[-1] == ":":
                    label = label[:-1]
                    label_suffix += ":"
                contents = u'<label for="%s"%s>%s<span style="color:red;">*</span>%s</label>' % (widget.id_for_label(id_), attrs, label, label_suffix)
            else:
                contents = u'<label for="%s"%s>%s</label>' % (widget.id_for_label(id_), attrs, unicode(contents))
        return mark_safe(contents)

def custom_inline_label_tag(self, contents=None, attrs=None):
    if attrs:
        if "class" in attrs.keys():
            attrs["class"] += " inline"
        else:
            attrs["class"] = "inline"
    else:
        attrs = {"class": "inline"}
    return self.label_tag(contents, attrs)
django_forms.BoundField.label_tag = custom_label_tag # override django method
django_forms.BoundField.inline_label_tag = custom_inline_label_tag
```

In my templates

```
<p>{{ form.fieldname.errors}}{{ form.fieldname.inline_label_tag }}{{form.fieldname}}</p>
OR
<p>{{ form.fieldname.errors}}{{ form.fieldname.label_tag }}{{form.fieldname}}</p>
```