# Tell if a Django Field is required from template

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm rendering a form. I would like to put a mark next to all the fields that must be filled in. Simple stuff usually... but I've no idea how to access that information!

```
{% if field.required %}REQUIRED!!{% endif %}
```

doesn't bring any love...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render form field with information that it is required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254046/how-to-render-form-field-with-information-that-it-is-required)

Answer (score 122, accepted):

```
{% if field.field.required %}
```

From [this snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/474/)

Answer (score 2):

I usually write out the html for each of my form elements, so I have a little more control over each one.  Then you can add an * for required or REQUIRED!!.

```
<p><label>Title: *<br />
{% if form.title.errors %}<ul class="errorlist">{{ form.title.errors }}</ul>{% endif %}
{{form.title}}
</label></p>    

<p><label>Category:<br />
{% if form.category.errors %}<ul class="errorlist">{{ form.category.errors }}</ul>{% endif %}
{{form.category}}
</label></p>
```

Comment: Writing out html for each element is buggy: if you change some html in `Title`, you may forget to change that value in `Category`. And, of course, DRY: don't repeat yourself.
So the best way is to write one html for all fields.

Comment: @MrKsn Writing out html for each element is not "buggy", that's not a good statement to make at all. Most people will write out their HTML for full control of forms, it's second nature to update the template once a field has been added or changed.

Comment: @JeffC Corresponding to the example above, there is no reason to use copy-paste. Of course, if someone has absolutely different fields with different decorations, it may be ok to describe every field explicitly. But many, many, [many programming errors are done](http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0068/) while using copy-paste.