# How do I put a a red asterisk to show a required field in a form in django?

Tags: django, forms, view, models

```
class ClientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    client_number = forms.IntegerField()
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=80)
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
    telephone = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    fax = forms.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    alternative_name = forms.CharField(max_length=80, required=False)
    alternative_address = forms.CharField(max_length=250, required=False)
    alternative_telephone = forms.CharField(max_length=20, required=False)
    alternative_email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
```

Some of these fields are required and some are not. For those that are required is there a way which I can add a red asterisk to say that this field is required?

Here is my form in html.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
<font>
<h3>Add Client</h3>
</font>
    <form method= "POST" action="">
        <font>
        <div id="form">
        <table>
            {{form.as_table}}
        </table>
        <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" STYLE="background-color:#E8E8E8; color:#181818 "/>
        </div>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render form field with information that it is required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254046/how-to-render-form-field-with-information-that-it-is-required)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to render form field with information that it is required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254046/how-to-render-form-field-with-information-that-it-is-required)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to render form field with information that it is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254046/how-to-render-form-field-with-information-that-it-is-required)