# overriding admin field label content in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am using admin forms for the CRUD operations. However, I want to add certain characters in the labels generated by the admin. For example, * in case the field is required. How can I accomplish it?

I can directly go into django admin code and add the * in there (in the file `contrib/admin/helpers.py` in this case) But it is not the right way. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no "great" way to do this, so your options will be css (add background img), subclassing form, template tags, or template modification. There are some good answers to this previous question here:

[How to render form field with information that it is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254046/how-to-render-form-field-with-information-that-it-is-required)