# How to highlight or mark * no blank(must be filled) field automatically in template of django?

Tags: django, templates, null, highlight

Since field is request while saving, is there any way to highlight or mark * them automatically while rendering html page?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to render form field with information that it is required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254046/how-to-render-form-field-with-information-that-it-is-required)

Comment: Are you using django forms? If yes, please show the relevant form definition.